# Partial match of string in array and return the key

Tags: php, arrays

how to search a partial string match in array and return the first occurrence of the key in array.
Example below

```
$keys = array(0 => 'Industrial acids', 1 => 'Industrial chemicals', 2 => 'ovens', 3 => 'Chemical companies');
```

Search for Indus must return 0

```
       Industrial must return 0
       chemi must return 1  
       Industrial chemi must return 1
```

Comment: 'how to search a partial string match in array ... ?' But what are you searching for? What is your 'partial string'?

Comment: $search='chemic';   to find the string chemic in array $keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple foreach

```
<?php
$index = 0;
$searchedString='chemic';
foreach($keys as $key => $value){
    if ($value == $searchedString){ //If you are searching the exact String $searchedString (here 'chemics'
        $index = $key;
        break; //To be sure it will be the first index
    }
}
echo $index;
?>
```

if You just want to know if 'chemic' is inside a string, use `strpos($value,$searchedString) !== false` instead of `$value == $searchedString`

Comment: Instead of `$value == $searchedString` they are probably looking for something like `stristr($search, $value) !== false`

Comment: it is not exact match, it must match given partial string in array.chemic must return key 1 but you function is returning 0 http://codepad.org/tyJAgfxA

Comment: @dbrumann i was already editing my post to include the second case when you posted your comment, but thanks!

Comment: @user3556434 changes `>=0` with `!== false` and it will work (I tested it)